# PHP Dropdown box Failing to Post

Tags: php, mysql

This may just be a late night stupidity issue, dropdown box populates fine, but when the submit button is pressed nothing is posted.

```
<?php
include("configlocal.php");

$selectedMake = $_REQUEST['select_make'];

mysql_connect ($host,$user,$pass);
@mysql_select_db($database) or die( "Unable to select database");

// Formulate Query
$select="SELECT Distinct make FROM vehicles order by make";

// Perform Query
$selection=mysql_query($select);
$num=mysql_numrows($selection);

echo '<form action="test1.php" method="post">';
echo '<select name"="select_make">';
for($i = 0; $i < $num ; $i++)
    {
    echo '<option value="' . $i . '">';
    echo mysql_result ($selection,$i,"make");
    echo '</option>';
    }

echo '</select>';
echo '<input type="submit" value="Search"/>';
echo '</form>';

if ($selectedMake != "")
{
echo $selectedMake;
}

?>
```

I'm giving up for the night, I have work in the morning, but any help pointing out the obvious would be appreciated.

Comment: Your quotes are faulty on the name attribute `name"="select_make"`

Comment: Is there an error on the test1.php page? Post the print_r($_POST) on that page.

Answer (score 3):

There is a unwanted double quote (`"`) near `name`

```
echo '<select name"="select_make">';
```

TO

```
echo '<select name="select_make">';
```

UPDATE: Don't use `$_REQUEST` it's not really safe. Use $_POST or $_GET for security reasons.

Don't use `mysql_*` functions, they will be deprecated soon. Use PDO ot MySqli functions for connecting database.

Comment: It is a good idea to look at the HTML code when page is rendered - these things are easier to spot.

Answer (score 0):

```
echo '<select name"="select_make">';
```

Error on that line with extra quotes.